# Is it possible to create a graph out of collected information stored in a Drupal database?

Tags: database, charts

I am new to Drupal. As a beginner I want to create a website which needs to store lots of information. And from the collected information (statistics), I want to map a graph (or chart) out of it.

**My Question**: Can it be done using Drupal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use Charts:
[Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts)

> Transform Data into Information. Charts are a very good way to
>   visualize a lot of data in a way that can be quickly digested.

Comment: Can you help in giving a step by step procedure or a good tutorial link in establishing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[Charts & Graphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts_graphs)**, **[Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts)** or **[View Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_charts)** module. Through this you can show information in the form of graph.

Answer (score 1):

Since the other answers to this question were posted, many things have happened regarding the documentation of the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module. So here is an updated version of what is available today.

The [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module is one of the [typical charting modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985#nativemodules) that can use [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) as one of its [Supported Charting Libraries](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985#supportedlibraries). Here is part of what's currently included on the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) project page:

> Transform **Data** into **Information**. Charts are a very good way to visualize a lot of data in a way that can be quickly digested.
>
> **Features**
>
> 1. **Wide chart type support**: Pie, Line, Bar, Column, Area or Scatter charts.
> 2. **API**: A Drupal-friendly syntax for creating charts easily, regardless of the underlying library.
> 3. **Views integration**: Display the Views results as charts.
> 4. **Examples**: The module includes lots of example charts for you to reference when building your own charts or chart library integration.
> 5. **Supported charting libraries**: out of the box, you may use either (the new) Google Charts (**GC** for short) or Highcharts  (**HC** for short) as the charting library.

To address the OPer's comment about 'step by step procedures' and 'documentation':

Start from the [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/233753) about the Charts module.

There are around 10 child pages there, with topics such as:

- [Getting started](https://www.drupal.org/node/2423033) (install, etc).
- [Charts Howtos](https://www.drupal.org/node/2435077) (all sorts of questions, similar to here on SE, though slightly different topics).
- [Create charts using Views](https://www.drupal.org/node/2313837), as documented in [Steps to create charts using the views UI](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426929).
- [Using the Charts API](https://www.drupal.org/node/2423431), for which various samples are available in the [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2423443) for the Charts module.
- ...

This should help a bit "to get started" ...

Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module,
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).